# passing / in the URL string causing an exception

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am getting exception when i have a `/` in the selected value from the drop-down list. When user selects `Prod1/TOXS` from drop-down list, and click on submit button it is calling `myservice.fetchData` where it is throwing an exception as it is constructing the URL as

```
applnURL+'/prodData/'+ Prod1/TOXS + '/productDetails.form'
```

Demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/HOaICuMKegzn9Or489cX?p=preview

html code:

```
  <select ng-model="selectedProd" ng-options="x for x in prodNames">
   </select>
```

js code:

```
 angular.module('checkboxExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
      $scope.prodNames = ['Prod1/TOXS', 'Prod2/XYA', 'BLACK','prod3as','Prod23sd/88X'];
      $scope.submitForm = function(){
        alert("submi form" + $scope.selectedProd);
        //service call
        /*  MyService.fetchData($scope.selectedProd){
          //logic
        }*/
      }
  }]);

  //service call
           /*     myservice.fetchData = function(selectedValue){
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    var randomh=Math.random();
                    var urlStr = applnURL+'/prodData/'+ selectedValue + '/productDetails.form?';
                    $http.get(repUrl)
                        .then(...
                        ...*/
```

Is there any way to pass `'/'` in the URL string.

Comment: Just to be pedantic (we're on the Internet after all) "/" is a *forward* slash, not a backslash.

Comment: encoding the value appended using encodeURIComponent() function should solve your issue.

Comment: What you describe doesn't make sense, the `$scope.selectedProd` holds a string and it should all work fine. Please provide a working code snippet that actually generate the error you describe.

Answer (score 1):

If `Prod1/TOXS` is the value of a string you have to put it in `""` to prevent JavaScript from interpreting them as variablenames.

In addition it would be wise to encode strings send in an URL with `encodeURIComponent()`

```js
var applnURL = "";
console.log(applnURL+'/prodData/'+ encodeURIComponent("Prod1/TOXS") + '/productDetails.form');
```